# How to remove items from a slice while ranging over it?

Tags: go

What is the best way to remove items from a slice while ranging over it?

For example:

```
type MultiDataPoint []*DataPoint

func (m MultiDataPoint) Json() ([]byte, error) {
    for i, d := range m {
        err := d.clean()
        if ( err != nil ) {
            //Remove the DP from m
        }
    }
    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

Comment: @YasirG.: That's for deleting from a `map`. The OP wants to delete from a `slice`.

Comment: ah true sorry for the wrong answer been awake for 25 hours now :S

Comment: Go desperately needs a **descending** range construct. Not having it causes a good deal of extra work.

Comment: How would that change anything? @Vector

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As you have mentioned elsewhere, you can allocate new memory block and copy only valid elements to it. However, if you want to avoid the allocation, you can rewrite your slice in-place:

```
i := 0 // output index
for _, x := range s {
    if isValid(x) {
        // copy and increment index
        s[i] = x
        i++
    }
}
// Prevent memory leak by erasing truncated values 
// (not needed if values don't contain pointers, directly or indirectly)
for j := i; j < len(s); j++ {
    s[j] = nil
}
s = s[:i]
```

Full example: http://play.golang.org/p/FNDFswPeDJ

Note this will leave old values after index `i` in the underlying array, so this [will leak memory](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoSlicesMemoryLeak) until the slice itself is garbage collected, if values are or contain pointers. You can solve this by setting all values to nil or the zero value from i until the end of the slice before truncating it.

Comment: No need for semicolons in Go

Comment: @Ectomorph: fixed; back then I was a C++ programmer – fortunately these days are gone and took semicolons with them.

Comment: Should be accepted answer. Much better than copying array on each removal.

Comment: @tomasz Would you care to elaborate on the implications of your `Note it'll leave some garbage` sentence?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I don't think my wording was very accurate here and my only intention was to warn people we're overwriting the original array, so there could be side-effects. Will edit.

Comment: Specifically if you have a slice of pointers, you can potentially leak those items at the end of the array, because the backing memory containing the original pointer is still alive to the GC. If you truncate a slice of pointers, always set the truncated pointers to nil. https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoSlicesMemoryLeak

Comment: Interesting, since [C++ does the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), only with algorithms you don't have to reimplement it each time!

Comment: To clarify, it is only the `nil` assignments that should be omitted when the values are not pointers, correct? The actual truncation `s = s[:i]` should be performed regardless of value type.

Comment: This doesn't work for 1 element in the slice

Answer (score 28):

I know its answered long time ago but i use something like this in other languages, but i don't know if it is the golang way.

Just iterate from back to front so you don't have to worry about indexes that are deleted. I am using the same example as Adam.

```
m = []int{3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5}

for i := len(m)-1; i >= 0; i-- {
    if m[i] < 5 {
        m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)
    }
}
```

Comment: simplest answer, should be the top one

Comment: Not efficient though, if removing more than 1 element. It copies array for every removed element. Removing 100 from 10'000 elements copies 500'000 (on average) elements. Where @tomasz solution copies 10'000. 50x faster.

Answer (score 17):

There might be better ways, but here's an example that deletes the even values from a slice:

```
m := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6}

deleted := 0
for i := range m {
    j := i - deleted
    if (m[j] & 1) == 0 {
        m = m[:j+copy(m[j:], m[j+1:])]
        deleted++
    } 
}
```

Note that I don't get the element using the `i, d := range m` syntax, since `d` would end up getting set to the wrong elements once you start deleting from the slice.

Comment: Although I just realized it is a lot straight forward (maybe less efficient?) to just create a second MultiDataPoint object, append valid stuff to it, and Marshal that. Don't know how I didn't see that in the first place :-/

Comment: I guess the efficiency depends on the expected ratio of deletions to the total number of elements. The code will most likely be more straight-forward though.

Comment: `for i, _ := ` should just be `for i := `

Comment: @newacct: Oops. Edited.

Comment: you should use the form `for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {` for the loop, the range might give you an `index out of range` error.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a more idiomatic Go way to remove elements from slices.

```
temp := s[:0]
for _, x := range s {
    if isValid(x) {
        temp = append(temp, x)
    }
}
s = temp
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/OH5Ymsat7s9

Note: The example and playground links are based upon @tomasz's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551116/12003457

Comment: Nice, simple solution.

Comment: For initialisation of temp, why do this `temp := s[:0]` instead of `temp := []int{}`. What's the difference?

Comment: @Daryll `s[:0]` zeros the length but keeps the same capacity of `s`, whereas `[]int{}` zeros both. It also avoids re-declaring the type.

Comment: Using s[:0] would reuse the same underlying array, while using []int{} would create a new array.

Comment: If a different goroutine updates the original s during this loop, this code will wipe the new data and take whatever is in temp. You need to put this whole block in a mutex.Lock() so it is safe for use

Answer (score 8):

One other option is to use a normal for loop using the length of the slice and subtract 1 from the index each time a value is removed. See the following example:

```
m := []int{3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5}

for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {
    if m[i] < 5 {
        m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)
        i-- // -1 as the slice just got shorter
    }
}
```

I don't know if `len()` uses enough resources to make any difference but you could also run it just once and subtract from the length value too:

```
m := []int{3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5}

for i, s := 0, len(m); i < s; i++ {
    if m[i] < 5 {
        m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)
        s--
        i--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)
```

Comment: Noteworthy: [Slice Tricks wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks)

Comment: I am trying to use this method on a slice of strings - I get this error: "cannot use m[i + 1:] (type []string) as type string in append"

It seems to be expecting a string not a slice of strings as the second parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: Nvmd - I just realized that "..." was actually apart of the code.

Comment: If you use this while iterating `m`, you will get `runtime error: slice bounds out of range`. That's what this question is about. You can use `m = append(m[:i], m[i+1:]...)` to delete an item from a slice but not while you are iterating through it with `for i, element := range m`.

Answer (score 2):

Now that Go has generics, you may use [slices.DeleteFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#DeleteFunc) like this:

```
m = slices.DeleteFunc(m, func(dp *DataPoint) bool {
    return dp.clean() != nil
})
```

"DeleteFunc" is a fancy name for "Filter" that emphasizes "return true for elements you want to remove".

See full code [in the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/jzx573zvkVQ).

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to count backwards but you do need to check that you're at the end of the array where the suggested `append()` will fail. Here's an example of removing duplicate positive integers from a sorted list:

```
// Remove repeating numbers
numbers := []int{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5}
log.Println(numbers)
for i, numbersCount, prevNum := 0, len(numbers), -1; i < numbersCount; numbersCount = len(numbers) {
    if numbers[i] == prevNum {
        if i == numbersCount-1 {
            numbers = numbers[:i]
        } else {
            numbers = append(numbers[:i], numbers[i+1:]...)

        }
        continue
    }
    prevNum = numbers[i]
    i++

}
log.Println(numbers)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v93MgtCQsaN

Answer (score 0):

I just implement a method which removes all nil elements in slice.

And I used it to solve a leetcode problems, it works perfectly.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * type ListNode struct {
 *     Val int
 *     Next *ListNode
 * }
 */
 func removeNil(lists *[]*ListNode) {
    for i := 0; i < len(*lists); i++ {
        if (*lists)[i] == nil {
            *lists = append((*lists)[:i], (*lists)[i+1:]...)
            i--
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid memory leaks, as suggested in @tomasz's answer, controlling the capacity of the underlying array with a [full slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec). Look at the following function that remove duplicates from a slice of integers:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func removeDuplicates(a []int) []int {

    for i, j := 0, 1; i < len(a) && j < len(a); i, j = i+1, j+1 {
        if a[i] == a[j] {
            copy(a[j:], a[j+1:])
            // resize the capacity of the underlying array using the "full slice expression"
            // a[low : high : max]
            a = a[: len(a)-1 : len(a)-1]
            i--
            j--
        }
    }
    return a
}

func main() {
    a := []int{2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 9, 9}
    fmt.Println(a)
    a = removeDuplicates(a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
// [2 3 3 3 6 9 9]
// [2 3 6 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

For reasons @tomasz has explained, there are issues with removing in place. That's why it is practice in golang not to do that, but to reconstruct the slice. So several answers go beyond the answer of @tomasz.

If elements should be unique, it's practice to use the keys of a map for this. I like to contribute an example of deletion by use of a map.

What's nice, the boolean values are available for a second purpose. In this example I calculate `Set a minus Set b`. As Golang doesn't have a real set, I make sure the output is unique. I use the boolean values as well for the algorithm.

The map gets close to `O(n)`. I don't know the implementation. `append()` should be `O(n)`. So the runtime is similar fast as deletion in place. Real deletion in place would cause a shifting of the upper end to clean up. If not done in batch, the runtime should be worse.

In this special case, I also use the map as a register, to avoid a nested loop over `Set a` and `Set b` to keep the runtime close to `O(n)`.

```
type Set []int

func differenceOfSets(a, b Set) (difference Set) {
    m := map[int]bool{}
    for _, element := range a {
        m[element] = true
    }
    for _, element := range b {
        if _, registered := m[element]; registered {
            m[element] = false
        }
    }
    for element, present := range m {
        if present {
            difference = append(difference, element)
        }
    }
    return difference
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [Sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) and [Binary search](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    // Our slice.
    s := []int{3, 7, 2, 9, 4, 5}

    // 1. Iterate over it.
    for i, v := range s {
        func(i, v int) {}(i, v)
    }

    // 2. Sort it. (by whatever condition of yours)
    sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        return s[i] < s[j]
    })

    // 3. Cut it only once.
    i := sort.Search(len(s), func(i int) bool { return s[i] >= 5 })
    s = s[i:]

    // That's it!
    fmt.Println(s) // [5 7 9]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LnF6o0yMJGT

Comment: This requires more code, is slower (sorting is generally not faster than O(n log n), while iteratively removing from the slice would be O(n)) and doesn't properly demonstrate how you'd use it to remove elements from a slice when you have a filter function and not a comparison function.

Comment: I believe this is more memory efficient and could be even faster as it doesn’t copy any element from a slice to another slice. Changing the whole structure of where data is stored for every element to be removed is dangerous and may cost a lot more than just iterating over a slice.