# Occasional 'slice bounds out of range' panic

Tags: go, websocket

I'm running a script that forwards webhooks to a WebSocket.
The part that sends the webhook to the WebSocket checks for inactive connections and tries to remove them when forwarding webhooks sometimes fails with this error:

```
http: panic serving 10.244.38.169:40958: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

(The IP/port is always different, this is just an example.)

Relevant code:

```
// Map holding all Websocket clients and the endpoints they are subscribed to
var clients = make(map[string][]*websocket.Conn)
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

// function to execute when a new client connects to the websocket
func handleClient(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, endpoint string) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    // ...
    // Add client to endpoint slice
    clients[endpoint] = append(clients[endpoint], conn)
}

// function to send a webhook to a websocket endpoint
func handleHook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, endpoint string) {
    msg := Message{}
    // ...   
    // Get all clients listening to the current endpoint
    conns := clients[endpoint]

    if conns != nil {
        for i, conn := range conns {
            if conn.WriteJSON(msg) != nil {
                // Remove client and close connection if sending failed
                conns = append(conns[:i], conns[i+1:]...)   // this is the line that sometimes triggers the panic
                conn.Close()
            }
        }
    }

    clients[endpoint] = conns
}
```

I cannot figure out why iterating over the connections and appending them sometimes triggers the panic.

Comment: In the error line slice index is getting incremented. It may go beyond the cap of slice and throw panic. What is the cap of slice ?

Comment: Thanks! Ran the race detector and managed to fix it with mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points that I'd like to say:

1. Make sure that your program has no race condition (eg. `clients` is globally accessible and should be protected if read/write or write/write
   happening concurrently).
2. When ranging over a slice `for [...] range [...]` you do not need to check if slice the non-nil as range handles that already (see the code I've shared).
3. It is happening to your sometimes because there are times when `conn.WriteJSON` is failing and returning an error and the buggy logic of deleting element while ranging over is making your program panic. (see the code I've shared)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var conns []string = nil

    // "if conns != nil" check is not required as "for [...] range [...]"
    // can handle that. It is safe to use for "range" directly.
    for i, conn := range conns {
        fmt.Println(i, conn)
    }

    conns = []string{"1", "2", "3"}
    
    // Will panic
    for i := range conns {
        fmt.Printf("access: %d, length: %d\n", i, len(conns))
        conns = append(conns[:i], conns[i+1:]...)
    }
}
```

In the example, you can see the index that you are trying to access it more than or equal to the length of the slice which is triggering the panic. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545743/how-to-remove-items-from-a-slice-while-ranging-over-it) should help you to correct your logic or you can use a map as well for storing connections but it again comes with its own caveats like no ordering guarantee i.e., in which order it reads from the map.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! I have implemented it in my code and so far no panic anymore.    

I ended up fixing the races with Mutex for now. It will probably slow down the execution if there are a lot of webhooks forwarded at the same time, so I'm thinking if there's something better than map to hold all the clients that could handle read/write at the same time without locks.     
 
Anyway, this works, marking it as solved!

Comment: But make sure to fix the `append` as well; because it might be the reason later on when WriteJSON fails. And if you have a high number of clients maybe you can use a fast KV store like badger (https://github.com/dgraph-io/badger) or sharded map or something like that and see if that helps. And yes, do benchmark.

Comment: Yes, I fixed append as well! So far no more panics in the last 20h. Will take a look at badger, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Great @Ephebopus!

Answer (score 0):

should be remove by indexs in array:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var conns []string = nil

    // "if conns != nil" check is not required as "for [...] range [...]"
    // can handle that. It is safe to use for "range" directly.
    for i, conn := range conns {
        fmt.Println(i, conn)
    }

    conns = []string{"1", "2", "3"}

    // Will panic
    indexs := []int{}
    for i := range conns {
        if i < 2 {
            indexs = append(indexs, i)
        }
    }
    for i, val := range indexs {
        index = val - i
        fmt.Printf("access: %d, length: %d\n", i, len(conns))
        conns = append(conns[:index], conns[index+1:]...)
    }
    fmt.Println(conns)
}
```